# Create two-column, vertically-stacked columns control for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, custom-controls, itemscontrol

This may be a rather long and involved question. Let me start by saying that I'm developing in C# and XAML.  I want to create a control that stacks the following template:

```
_____________
|           |
| Text      |
| Image     |
| More Text |
|___________|
```

for a sequence of items, in two columns, like so:

```
______ ______
|    | |    |
| 1  | | 2  |
|____| |    |
|    | |____|
| 3  | |    |
|    | | 4  |
|    | |____|
|____| |    |
|    | | 5  |
| 6  | |    |
|    |
```

Notice that they are ordered first by height and then left to right.

This is relatively simple to do as a two column grid with a vertical stack panel in each.

To me, this is a representation of a sequence of items, so it makes sense to render this as a control that inherits from ItemsControl.

How would I go about doing that? Setting an ItemTemplate seems obvious, everything else escapes me.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want something very similar to a wrap panel?

Comment: The documentation for a Wrap Panel states: "By default, the elements within a wrap panel are placed horizontally from left-to-right, top-to-bottom, but you can also place them vertically from top-to-bottom, left-to-right." My situation is that elements needs to be placed horizontally, from top-to-bottom, left-to-right, if that makes sense.  I believe that a Wrap Panel would not put the 5th element where it is, rather it would go to the next line.

Really, I don't care too much about the algorithm, I can figure that out, I just want to be able to manually lay out items in an ItemsControl.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, it wouldn't put it there, I just wanted to clarify :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we should use the `ListBox` and change the *`ItemsPanel`* of ListBox. We customize a panel as ItemsPanel, definition the *`column property`* and override method of `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`.

Code is located below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TravelHelper_WP8
{
    public class CustomPanel : Panel
    {
        public CustomPanel()
        {
            /**default 2 columns**/
            ColumnCount = 2;
            columnHeight = new double[ColumnCount];
            this.UseLayoutRounding = true;
        }

        static double[] columnHeight;

        public int ColumnCount
        {
            get { return (int)this.GetValue(ColumnCountProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(ColumnCountProperty, value); }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ColumnCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnCount", typeof(int), typeof(CustomPanel), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback((o, e) =>
        {
            columnHeight = new double[(int)e.NewValue];
            if (o == null || e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
                return;
            o.SetValue(ColumnCountProperty, e.NewValue);
        })));

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            int indexY = this.Children.Count / ColumnCount;
            if (this.Children.Count % ColumnCount > 0) indexY++;
            int flagY = 0;
            Size resultSize = new Size(0, 0);
            #region<---- Measure Value

            for (int i = 0; i < indexY; i++)//Column
            {
                if (i == indexY - 1)
                {
                    int residual = Children.Count - i * ColumnCount;
                    if (Children.Count <= ColumnCount)
                    {
                        residual = Children.Count;
                    }

                    for (int h = 0; h < residual; h++)
                    {
                        Children[ColumnCount * flagY + h].Measure(availableSize);
                        resultSize.Width = (Children[ColumnCount * flagY + h].DesiredSize.Width) * ColumnCount;
                        columnHeight[h] += Children[ColumnCount * flagY + h].DesiredSize.Height;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < ColumnCount; y++)
                    {
                        Children[ColumnCount * flagY + y].Measure(availableSize);
                        resultSize.Width = (Children[ColumnCount * flagY + y].DesiredSize.Width) * ColumnCount;
                        columnHeight[y] += Children[ColumnCount * flagY + y].DesiredSize.Height;
                    }
                    flagY++;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            resultSize.Height = columnHeight.Max();
            return resultSize;
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < columnHeight.Count(); i++)
            {
                columnHeight[i] = 0;
            }
            int indexY = this.Children.Count / ColumnCount;
            if (this.Children.Count % ColumnCount > 0) indexY++;
            int flagY = 0;
            double flagX = 0;

            #region<------Layout
            for (int i = 0; i < indexY; i++)//Column
            {
                finalSize.Width = (Children[i].DesiredSize.Width) * ColumnCount;
                if (i == indexY - 1)
                {
                    flagX = 0;
                    int residual = Children.Count - i * ColumnCount;
                    if (Children.Count <= ColumnCount)
                    {
                        residual = Children.Count;
                    }
                    for (int h = 0; h < residual; h++)
                    {
                        Children[ColumnCount * i + h].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(flagX, columnHeight[h]), Children[ColumnCount * i + h].DesiredSize));
                        columnHeight[h] += Children[ColumnCount * flagY + h].DesiredSize.Height;
                        flagX += Children[ColumnCount * i + h].DesiredSize.Width;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < ColumnCount; y++)
                    {
                        Children[ColumnCount * flagY + y].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(flagX, columnHeight[y]), Children[ColumnCount * i + y].DesiredSize));
                        columnHeight[y] += Children[ColumnCount * flagY + y].DesiredSize.Height;
                        flagX += Children[ColumnCount * flagY + y].DesiredSize.Width;
                    }
                    flagX = 0; flagY++;
                }
            }

            #endregion

            return finalSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I had to change the arranging and measuring algorithms this was exactly what I needed to help me get to the finish line. Thanks.